# Can WHS backup Windows Server 2003/2008 Servers too?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-home-server

I like the automatic backup feature - but perhaps Windows Server has its own function that I don't know of. Is there one?

I also like the scheme for data redundancy in Windows Home Server, but I don't know if it will work with Windows Server 2003/2008 or if it is crippled to only work with XP/Vista/7.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work with Windows Server 2003, but it does work with Windows Server 2008. I don't think it is supported, but I have it working on my home network. It is backing up my Windows Server 2008 machine each night. I haven't tried to restore it yet since I haven't needed to, but it should work since it is getting backed up.

Comment: "I haven't tried to restore it yet since I haven't needed to, but it should work..." Famous last words? :)

Comment: Well I have tested getting files off the home server that have been backed up, just haven't had to do a full restore yet. And still haven't. :)